# How should I document function calls?

Tags: documentation, coding-standards

Reading the [WordPress PHP Documentation Standards](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/inline-documentation-standards/php-documentation-standards/), I can't see anywhere that mentions how to document a function call such as `add_action( 'foo', 'bar' );`

Should I be documenting function calls and, if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't document function calls, but function definitions. Because the function could be called unlimited times, right? So it makes no sense to document functions when they are called.

If you document the call, then probably because you do some things you want to remember later - or let other following developers know. But normally, I would say, that shouldn't happen - in a perfect world.

Now the hook system is somewhat different from normal calls, which might be the reason for the confusion. But actually it isn't, the function `add_action()` itself is documented, so it is about the hook and the function used. Lets look at your example:

```
add_action( 'foo', 'bar' );
```

Where `foo` is the hook and `bar` is the function. For this you probably have to go at it like @birgire shows it in his answer.

I'm assuming you know how to document the function, you linked the correct document. There you find two sections about documenting hooks too, which does apparently only apply to `do_action()` and `apply_filters()`.

- [4. Hooks (Actions and Filters)](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/inline-documentation-standards/php-documentation-standards/#4-hooks-actions-and-filters); example:

```
    /**
     * Summary.
     *
     * Description.
     *
     * @since x.x.x
     *
     * @param type  $var Description.
     * @param array $args {
     *     Short description about this hash.
     *
     *     @type type $var Description.
     *     @type type $var Description.
     * }
     * @param type  $var Description.
     */
```

- [4.1 Duplicate Hooks](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/inline-documentation-standards/php-documentation-standards/#4-1-duplicate-hooks); example:

```
/** This action is documented in path/to/filename.php */
```

This is the official part.

Personally like to add something like this:

```
/**
 * (Here is the official part)
 *
 * @hooked bar - 10
 */
do_action( 'foo' );
```

I do this on the finishing touches of a project, because I find it somewhat helpful and informational. I did not come up with that, but don't ask me where it is from, might be from WC. Additionally I'd like to note that it is probably not good practice. The schema here is

```
@hooked function_name - priority
```

Answer (score 5):

If there were a special WordPress core standard, for such function calls, one would expect it to be used in this file:

```
/wp-includes/default-filters.php
```

the *mother of hook setup calls*.

Skimming through that file, we see that there is at most a single comment line per function call:

```
// Slugs
add_filter( 'pre_term_slug', 'sanitize_title' );
```

Some calls are grouped under a comment:

```
// Mime types
add_filter( 'pre_post_mime_type', 'sanitize_mime_type' );
add_filter( 'post_mime_type', 'sanitize_mime_type' );
```

or even like this:

```
// Format text area for display.
foreach ( array( 'term_description' ) as $filter ) {   
        add_filter( $filter, 'wptexturize'  );
        add_filter( $filter, 'convert_chars'    );
        add_filter( $filter, 'wpautop'          );
        add_filter( $filter, 'shortcode_unautop');
}
```

So I would suggest you to do what makes sense for your code and helps make it more  readable.

We can also enhance the readability with *descriptive* callbacks. For example:

```
// BAD:
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_11' );

// BETTER:
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_remove_blacklisted_words' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight @birgire, it seems a single line comment is enough when it comes to documenting function calls and a dockblock only for the function definition. +1 from me